# Unable to get results using AND condition

Tags: mysql, sql

When I execute the following query then I don't get any results:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts_cstm WHERE id = '123' AND ftrere!='test'
```

And when I run the following query then it returns the result:

```
SELECT * FROM  contacts_cstm  WHERE ( id = '123')
```

Following is the table definition along with sample insert statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts_cstm` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `ftrere` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `contacts_cstm` (`id`, `ftrere`) VALUES
('123', NULL);
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` fails `<>` just like it fails `=`.  Use a null-safe comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts_cstm
WHERE id = 123 AND NOT (ftrere <=> 'test')
```

Note that [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) is MySQL's bespoke NULL-safe comparison operator.  This is equivalent to the standard SQL operator `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`.

Or be explicit about the `NULL` comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts_cstm
WHERE id = 123 AND (ftrere <> 'test' OR ftrere IS NULL);
```

Note:  `id` looks like a number so I dropped the single quotes for the comparison.

Comment: This is a good answer.  I'd only add that I tend to use COALESCE (or ISNULL if it's SQL Server) for null comparisons, because it's easier than writing an OR statement.  So for example, WHERE id = 123 AND ISNULL(ftrere, '') != 'test'

Comment: @Jim . . . The question is tagged MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Worked like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: @GordonLinoff isn't COALESCE an ANSI standard?  According to the interweb, COALESCE certainly is supported in MySQL.  I know I also gave an example with ISNULL which is SQL Server specific, but I said that outright, and COALESCE is used in the same way.

Comment: @Jim . . . I don't follow your comment.  The Standard `NULL` safe inequality operator is `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` and neither MySQL nor SQL Server supports that.  The appropriate operator here, though, is a `NULL`-safe comparison if available.

Comment: I'm super late responding, but you said "The question is tagged MySQL".  And my original comment was still relevant to MySQL.  COALESCE(ftrere, '') != 'test' is my preferred approach to solve the OP's original problem - its more concise than writing (ftrere <> 'test' OR ftrere IS NULL) and it accomplishes the same thing